# int[][] to int[] using the System.arracopy method

Tags: java, arrays

If I want to convert an `int[][]` array into an `int[]` in java, I use the code shown underneath.

```
final int width = 3, height = 4;
final int[][] source = new int[width][height];
final int[] destination = new int[width * height];
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
     for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
     {
          destination[x * width + y] = source[x][y];
     }
}
```

I was just recently introduced to the `System.arraycopy` method. It is probably the most efficient way to copy an array in java. Therefore, I tried to implement it in a similar way shown underneath.

```
final int width = 3, height = 4;
final int[][] source = new int[width][height];
final int[] destination = new int[width * height];
for (int index = 0; index < source.length; index++)
{
    System.arraycopy(source[index], 0, destination, source[index].length, source[index].length);
}
```

However, the resulting array is heavily distorted and does not represent the original array in any way.

Comment: When an IDE warns you about how you are using a method ... the simple thing is to turn to the javadoc of that method and read that really carefully. In other words: your goal should be to always understand exactly what the code you are writing is doing. Lajos gave you a nice answer, but in the end ... he is just quoting javadoc, isn't he ;-)

Comment: Since you have to loop your calls to `System.arraycopy` you may want to make sure you are actually gaining performance by going with this implementation.  I could see it possibly being slower for arrays with a very small height due to the overhead of invoking the method, depending how the compiler deals with it etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
final int width = 3, height = 4;
final int[][] source = new int[width][height];
final int[] destination = new int[width * height];
for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++)
     System.arraycopy(source[i], 0, destination, i * width, height);
```

If you want it to work in general, cases where each sub-array in source is different size, you want this:

```
int totalLength = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++)
   totalLength += source[i].length;
final int[] destination = new int[totalLength];
for (int len, i = 0, index = 0; i < source.length; i++, index += len)
        System.arraycopy(source[i], 0, destination, index, len = source[i].length);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Parameters
>
> ```
> src − This is the source array.
>
> srcPos − This is the starting position in the source array.
>
> dest − This is the destination array.
>
> destPos − This is the starting position in the destination data.
>
> length − This is the number of array elements to be copied.
> ```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_arraycopy.htm

You need to do this inside a loop:

```
final int width = 3, height = 4;
final int[][] source = new int[width][height];
final int[] destination = new int[width * height];
for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++)
    System.arraycopy(source[i], 0, destination, i * width, source[i].length);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. Is there really no other way to do that? I believe that it is possible without a `for` loop, but my memory might just be playing a trick on me.

Comment: @NiklasSimandi you cannot copy an array of arrays into an array using arraycopy. You can, however put the solution I gave above into a method and use that. You might have seen such a method being used.

Comment: *"I believe that it is possible without a for loop, but my memory might just be playing a trick on me."* - It is.

Comment: Why do I always get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when I run the same code?

Comment: @NiklasSimandi because I have passed the wrong value for destPost. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Despite your edited answer, the code is still raising an exception when running. Am I doing something wrong? I copied the exact code that you posted. Something that is weird as well is the fact that you wrote `var i = 0` where it should be `int i = 0`.

Comment: @NiklasSimandi the var is coming from the fact that I am working in another language. It should be int :)

Comment: @LajosArpad But even if I change it to an `int`, the problem is not resolved. What causes the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and how can I fix it?

Comment: @NiklasSimandi the last parameter was destination.length. source[i].length is the correct value. Also destPos should be 0. Sorry for the mistakes, I have no Java environment in front of me, hence the typos.

Comment: No worries. Thank you anyway.

Comment: The code is still plainly wrong. The destination position may not be `0`. This will copy all source arrays to the *beginning* of the destination array.

Answer (score 0):

The details here might depend on whether the array is known to be rectangular or not. But regardless of that, I'd recommend to simply pull this into a utility method that is implemented generically and works for all sorts of input arrays.

An example is shown below. The `flatten` method is what you're looking for.

The `flattenWithStreams` is just an example showing that this can concisely be solved with streams. I did not do a detailed performance analysis, but the approach that is using `arraycopy` seems to be faster.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FlattenArrays
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        test();
    }

    private static void test()
    {
        int[][] source = new int[3][];
        source[0] = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
        source[1] = new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        source[2] = new int[] { 7, 8, 9 };

        int destinationA[] = flatten(source);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(destinationA));

        int destinationB[] = flattenWithStream(source);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(destinationB));
    }

    private static int[] flatten(int array[][])
    {
        int length = 0;
        for (int a[] : array)
        {
            length += a.length;
        }
        int destination[] = new int[length];
        int offset = 0;
        for (int a[] : array)
        {
            System.arraycopy(a, 0, destination, offset, a.length);
            offset += a.length;
        }
        return destination;
    }

    private static int[] flattenWithStream(int array[][])
    {
        return Stream.of(array).flatMapToInt(a -> IntStream.of(a)).toArray();
    }
}
```